# Issues with psycopg2

Tags: python, pip, psycopg2

I have `import psycopg2` in my code yet I keep getting `ImportError: No module named psycopg2`when I try to run it. I've tried

> `└─$ pip3 install psycopg2` 
> `└─$ pip install psycopg2-binary`  
> `└─$ sudo apt-get install build-dep python-psycopg2`

anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Not without more information. Are you working in a `virtualenv`? Where did you install `psycopg2` to, the system or a virtualenv? Where are running the code, in a client, in a module, editor, some where else? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: Default location of package in debian is /usr/lib/python*.*/dist-packages/psycopg2

Comment: @AdrianKlaver where would I find where I installed it? just spun up a new Kali VM and intalled Visual on it to edit the code and add "import psycopg2". Running it on terminal.

Comment: @Cybervitexus I have python2.7 , python3 and python3.9

Comment: Ok so when I run it as python3 I don't have an issue but I know I need to run it on python so how can I amend it?

Comment: did you try pip2 install psycopg2. Are you sure you are using python3 or python2?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is: Which Python version do you want to have `psycopg2`? I am posting 2 solutions, since I'm not sure which one is helpful in your case:

- If you want to install it for Python 2, `python -m pip install psycopg2` should do this.
- If you want to install the package for Python 3, you can run `python3 -m pip` or `pip3`. This should avoid confusions with Python 2 installations.